# Asp.net with iis6/gzip : can a dynamic page send back its content without compression?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, gzip

When gzip is activated in an IIS6 website for dynamic content (aspx pages) : it seems it compress all responses.

Is there a way to exclude just a page ?

From best to worst solutions :

- by adding a specific response header (which could be done dynamicly) ?
- <s>by providing some specials markups in the web.config ?</s> (seems not possible under iis6/gzip)
- by doing some configurations under iis6 ?

Comment: I'm just curious... why?

Comment: I know how to do this with IIS 7, but not IIS 6....

Comment: Why ? because we use a "rich client", and for one request, this client can't understand gzipped content ;-(. We can't touch the client ... so we need to solve this trouble on the server sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a custom extension that is not compressed.

Comment: So ... I will setup a httphandler for *.ashx. And put the code of that page in the handler ...
And, are you really sure that under IIS6, you can set gzip to not compress *.ashx files ?
If that's right : it's the only way to go. And I will do it on monday in the second revision ;-)